# Grinding type sound in steering wheel of a 2011 Mitsubishi Lancer EX

Tags: noise, steering, mitsubishi, lancer

Form the past days my car is having an issue when I turn the steering wheel (left to right) at the start point.and the same sound (grinding type) dissapear while I am on the continuous run.just a week ago I have replaced the new alloy wheel and tyre of car, from then to now I am getting the same sound.

***one more thing the earlier alloy wheel was 16 in  and the new one which I replaced is 17 inch with the tyre. does it matters to the steering wheel sound..?***

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you change all 4 wheels from 16 to 17 inch?  If not, which wheel did you change?

Comment: All 4 wheel changed from 16 to 17 inch.

Comment: Is your power steering fluid reservoir topped up with fluid?

Comment: yes. two days ago fluid is topped up.

Comment: yes.fluid is topped up 2 days ago

Comment: Are you bigger wheels rubbing on plastic or other components in your wheel well while you drive?  If you put larger wheels on your car and now it makes a continual grinding noise it seems the issue most likely revolves around the last change you made to the system.  Your last change is bigger wheels so.......have your checked that?

Answer (score 1):

Your rubber is grinding against the front wheel well liner - there is a plastic area there your tire grinds against on full lock because you upsized your wheels.

Solution - take a heat gun and warm up the area where the tire grinds, then push it out a bit. Don't overheat as it easily melts.

Here: [image]